# How to determine which image is loaded in a BitBtn?

Tags: delphi, button

I want a sorting button for a table in Delphi. I have a TBitBtn with a Glyph (an up arrow). When that button is pressed, I want something like this to happen:

```
if btbSort.Glyph := 'Up.bmp' do
   Sort from down to up
or else
   Sort from up to down
```

Does this make sense?

There doesn't seem to be a property for the "loaded glyph".

Comment: Probably easier to use the hint property.  Set it at the same time as the button glyph then  check it when needed.

Comment: You should keep the GUI and internal data state separated. Since it is you who set the glyph of the button, you know what it is. You don't need to ask the button for it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to ask the Button which Glyph is loaded, because it does not keep track of that information.  So you have to keep track of it yourself, for instance by using the button's `Tag` propety, eg:

```
btbSort.Glyph.LoadFromFile('Up.bmp');
btbSort.Tag := 1;
...
if btbSort.Tag = 1 then begin
   // Sort from down to up ...
end
else begin
   // Sort from up to down ...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat it like a write-only property as there's nothing simple to read. The Good News is the Glyphs are usually very small and load up quickly. If the control lets you use an ImageList, then all you need to do is change the ImageIndex.

You need the glyph to be set by an event that changes it. Start it off in a known state (eg., "on" or "off") with the correlated image, then load up the other image each time the state changes. You could have several states that you want to reflect, not just two.

However, you can assign glyphs with multiple images, like pages, up to four I think: up, mouse-down, mouse-up, and down (or something similar). It will pick the appropriate glyph to show. That's probably explained somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

It's like a dance: you need to decide who's leading and who's following -- the button's state or the (external) sort order flag's state.

Comment: He's not asking how to change the image, but how to tell which image is showing.

Comment: It's basically a WRITE-ONLY property. You TELL it which image to show. There's no way of ASKING it. Maybe get the underlying bitmap and do a CRC or MP5 of it, and then use that to look it up in a list. But that's a lot of work as opposed to simply SETTING IT to what you want.

Comment: Yes, that is the way you use it, but that's not what he was asking how to do.

Comment: He's asking how to READ a WRITE-ONLY PROPERTY. There's NOTHING TO READ! What's the point of repeating yourself when you know there's NO ANSWER TO HIS QUESTION?

Comment: No, he was not asking how to read a write-only property.  He was asking how to determine whether he should sort up or down, based on what arrow was showing on the button.  His also said that he had attempted to read the 'write-only' property as a way to do that, but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

A `TBitBtn` does have a `Glyph` property which is a `TBitmap`, but I'm not sure you could readily use that to determine which arrow is showing.

However, taking a lead from David Schwartz' answer, perhaps the best way is to create a `TImageList` containing the up and down arrows, then set `ImageIndex` of the button to the arrow required.  When the user clicks the button, see which number `ImageIndex` is currently set to, and sort accordingly.

Comment: No, that's certainly not the best way. The best way is to separate GUI from internal data structures. If you want to know the current sorting state, ask your internal data structures. Don't ask the button you yourself updated a few moments ago.

Comment: I mentioned that, and it still does not address the question of how to ask the component what image it's displaying. It's a WRITE-ONLY PROPERTY, although you CAN get the bitmap. Do you have a specific suggestion as to how to ask the component what image it's currently displaying?